# Trouble binding a complex UI with angularJs data-binding

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an angularJs directive which binds a collection to the UI shown below:

The binding is all fine currently, the only problem is with setting the highlighted styles.  The tiels which are highlighted with a boarder are grouped.

[image: This is the UI binding I want to create]

Following is my data structure:

```
[ {bandwidth: 0
 cardInterface: 0
 groupEnd: false
 groupStart: false
 grouped: false
 id: -1
 signalingTimeSlot: 1
 splitTimeSlot: false},
 {
 bandwidth: 0
 cardInterface: 0
 groupEnd: false
 groupStart: false
 grouped: false
 id: -1
 ignalingTimeSlot: 2
 splitTimeSlot: false
},
{
 bandwidth: 0
 cardInterface: 0
 groupEnd: false
 groupStart: false
 grouped: false
 id: -1
 signalingTimeSlot: 4
 splitTimeSlot: false
 }, {
 bandwidth: 192
 cardInterface: 0
 groupEnd: false
 groupStart: true
 grouped: true
 id: 0
  signalingTimeSlot: 16
  splitTimeSlot: false
  timeSlotGroup: [ here there are 3 of the same object type which needs to be grouped]
 }]
```

Following is the directive template:

```
<div class="timeSlotWrapper">
<div ng-repeat-start="t in timeSlots | filter: {cardInterface : cardSlotId * 2}"  time-slot-obj="t" class="timeSlotItem"
     ng-click="timeSlotClick(cardId, $index, 0)" >{{ t.signalingTimeSlot }}</div>
   <!--<div ng-repeat-start="t in timeSlots | filter: {cardInterface : cardSlotId * 2}"  time-slot-obj="t" class="timeSlotItem"-->
        <!--ng-click="timeSlotClick(cardId, $index, 0)" ng-if="!t.grouped">{{ t.signalingTimeSlot }}</div>-->
   <!--<div class="configured" ng-if="t.timeSlotGroup.length > 0">-->
       <!--<div time-slot-obj="t1" ng-repeat="t1 in t.timeSlotGroup"  ng-click="timeSlotClick(cardId, $index, 0)" class="timeSlotItem">{{ t1.signalingTimeSlot }}</div>-->
   <!--</div>-->
   <br ng-repeat-end ng-if="(timeSlotCount == 31 && t.signalingTimeSlot === 15) || (timeSlotCount == 24 && t.signalingTimeSlot === 12)"/>
```

Notice the commented lines where I try to break the collection and display the grouped tiles with a separate style. But this makes each group appear on different lines rather than on the same line.

Comment: This seems like a CSS problem. Try using `<span>`'s or set `display: inline-block`

Comment: could you create a plnkr or a fiddle for this ?